# Is it possible to use the bluetoothctl write command to send serial data?

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, bluez

Is it possible to use the bluetoothctl write command to send serial data?

For example, I know that I can not do this exactly but can I have something to the effect that writes

```
btltoothctl write "this is an example"
```

Or is there another command that can do this within Bluetoothctl. Any information would be helpful. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bluetooth supports emulating a serial port connection between two devices. Then you can send your data as if the were a physical serial cable connecting the two devices.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is using `rfcomm bind ...` command.

use bluetoothctl scan and pair the target device, then bind the serial device with:

```
sudo rfcomm bind 0 C9:5B:CE:A4:97:C7
```

so it will create a device as

```
ls /dev/rfcomm0
```

then you can use any tool (eg `dd`) to write/read data from this pipe.

When done, you can use to release:

```
rfcomm release 0
```

and `bluetoothctl` to disconnect/unpair the device.

Comment: Ya, great, thanks. I have been trying for a while but I have been having a problem with that where I keep getting an error saying ` Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down`  and I have no idea how to fix it. I explain the problem in more detail at this link. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343815/cant-connect-rfcomm-socket-host-is-down  If you have any idea what to do about that that would also be very helpful. Thanks for the help so far though.