# Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have bluez 5.4.3 and I am attempting to communicate with a ble device through minicom. These two deceives (my computer and a bluno nano) are alreadt paired and this has been my method so far.

```
#bluetoothctl
# pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
# exit
```

Everything is working well so far then...

```
#sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 1 &
[1] 3665
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your local bluetooth hci device is down.

Try `hciconfig` to get current device name and status, and you can use `hciconfig hci0 up` where hci0 is your device name.