# How to use serial communication over bluetooth (using linux kernel 5.10 and bluez 5.55)

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

Basically I want to use a serial interface of a bluetooth device.
In my particular example its the [meshtastic-matrix-relay](https://github.com/geoffwhittington/meshtastic-matrix-relay/) connecting via serial/bluetooth to a RAK4631 (NRF52 based) device. The application requires a serial interface, like it would be `/dev/ttyUSB0` for an USB serial connection.

What I have researched is that in the past that worked by pairing the device with `bluetoothctl` and after that using the command `rfcomm bind 0 00:11:22:33:44:55 1` to later use `/dev/rfcomm0` as serial interface for other applications.
Until this point this works in Debian11/bullseye using kernel 5.10.0-23-amd64 and bluez 5.55-3.1 **but:** no application is able to use that `/dev/rfcomm0` interface.

I tried following hints/recommendations, but am still not able to use any application with `/dev/rfcomm0`:

- [Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343815/cant-connect-rfcomm-socket-host-is-down)
- [Is it possible to use the bluetoothctl write command to send serial data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343592/is-it-possible-to-use-the-bluetoothctl-write-command-to-send-serial-data)
- [How to I connect a raw serial terminal to a bluetooth connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248817/how-to-i-connect-a-raw-serial-terminal-to-a-bluetooth-connection)
- [Bluetooth RFCOMM does not work anymore](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=43022)
- [Serial over Bluetooth - Raspberry Pi Projects](https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/bluetooth/serial-over-bluetooth)
- [Bluetooth auf dem Raspberry Pi 3 einrichten (Seite 2) (german)](https://www.raspberry-pi-geek.de/ausgaben/rpg/2016/04/bluetooth-auf-dem-raspberry-pi-3-einrichten/2/)
- [USING BLE DEVICES WITH A RASPBERRY PI](https://www.argenox.com/library/bluetooth-low-energy/using-raspberry-pi-ble/)
- [Setting up a bluetooth device for use with serial communication in Linux](https://blog.joosten-industries.nl/posts/Setting-up-a-bluetooth-device-for-use-with-serial-communication-in-Linux/)

The last referenced link talks about `sdptool` but using this I am unable to browse any paired bluetooth device (to know the rfcomm channel, if for any reason its not `1`), one example:

```
# sdptool browse F4:46:DC:C5:A2:12
Failed to connect to SDP server on F4:46:DC:C5:A2:12: Host is down
```

In several old threads in different forums people recommend to use `bluetoothd --compat` but this does not help either.

Some people say that rfcomm (next to other bluetooth utils) is deprecated, but neither I could find a proof to that nor could I find an alternative or any explanation as to how this should be done nowadays.

(just to be clear, there is nothing wrong with the bluetooth device at all, because I can use it perfectly fine over bluetooth from my smartphone with the meshtastic app)